# Shopify get nav handle from a link

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is that possible to get nav's handle or name from a Url inside that nav?

Let say i have a Url of a collection `https://avasahome.myshopify.com/collections/ABC` that is inside a `ABC Test` nav which the handle is `abc-test`.

Can i get `abc-test` from the Url `https://avasahome.myshopify.com/collections/ABC`?

Please help me with this cause i found no document about this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can. `$('.nav__item')` will give you all the navigation items in the page. Get the text inside all the child elements.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas Thank you for helping me! can you be more specific? Cause i don't think `$('.nav__item')` is for `liquid`

Comment: What is your usecase? Do you want the text on page load or do you want the text when a navigation link is clicked? All javascript code will work in liquid files!

Comment: Like this, i'm inside `ABC` collection page, and that collection is inside a `ABC Test` nav, i need to get the handle of that nav from the `ABC` collection page, is that possible?

Comment: Please can you share the liquid code that you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your liquid file. This is basically a function which invoked will return you the Nav Link Text

```
get_nav = function(){
  var i, len, nav, ref;

  ref = $('.nav__link');
  for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
    nav = ref[i];
    if (nav.href === document.location.href) {
      alert(nav.text);
      //return nav.text;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will assign your desired value as `retrievedLinkHandle`:

```
{%- assign retrievedLinkHandle = false -%}
{%- for link in nav.links -%}
  {%- if link.type == 'collection_link' and link.object.id == collection.id -%}
    {%- assign retrievedLinkHandle = link.title | handle -%}
    {%- break -%}
  {%- endif -%}  
{%- endfor -%}
```